# How to get running total of unique IDs

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbeaver

I need to get the running total of unique Ids

```
select ID, min(date_time)
,case when ID is null then 0 else 1 end as New_ID
,SUM(New_ID) over (order by ID) as runningTotal_ID
          from Table1
          Group by 1
```

or maybe if I can directly count
`select Id, count(Id) over (order by ID) as Running Total`

But tied this it is giving me 10000... count but there are only 200 IDs

Can anyone please help me out here!

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  It is not clear how you want the running total to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` . . . assuming you want them the `id`s are assign in order:

```
select t1.*, dense_rank() over (order by id) as runningTotalId
from Table1 t1;
```

If not, you can mark the first an use a cumulative sum:

```
select t1.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by datetime) as runningTotalId
from (select t1.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by datetime) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t
```